# Android SearchView searchIcon(magnifying class when collapsed) right padding

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, searchview

I 'm trying to integrate a SearchView, on a custom Toolbar I 'm making.

The requirements are:

1) 2 ActionMenuViews

2) Centered Title

I have also subclassed SearchView to make it full width, so, apart from overriding onMeasure and applying a custom MaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE), I, also. applied this terrible hack found online to remove the SearchView container's margins.

```
    // Terrible hack (1) to set SearchView's main container margin to 0
LinearLayout searchEditFrame = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.search_edit_frame); // Get the Linear Layout
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) searchEditFrame.getLayoutParams();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    params.setMarginStart(0);
} else {
    params.leftMargin = 0;
}
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    params.setMarginEnd(0);
} else {
    params.rightMargin = 0;
}

searchEditFrame.setLayoutParams(params);
// End terrible hack (1)
```

I also took the liberty (sic) and applied similar logic to the magnifying glass ImageView directly.

```
    // Terrible hack (2) to remove hardcoded padding from search icon magnifying glass icon
ImageView magIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.search_mag_icon);

params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    params.setMarginStart(0);
} else {
    params.leftMargin = 0;
}
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    params.setMarginEnd(0);
} else {
    params.rightMargin = 0;
}
magIcon.setLayoutParams(params);

// End terrible hack (2)
```

(remember the ids are from abs_search_view.xml and they seem to match)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- This is actually used for the badge icon *or* the badge label (or neither) -->
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/search_badge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
            android:drawablePadding="0dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/search_button"
            style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/abc_searchview_description_search" />

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_edit_frame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layoutDirection="locale">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/search_mag_icon"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/abc_dropdownitem_icon_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:visibility="gone"
                style="@style/RtlOverlay.Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.MagIcon" />

        <!-- Inner layout contains the app icon, button(s) and EditText -->
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/search_plate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <view class="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$SearchAutoComplete"
                  android:id="@+id/search_src_text"
                  android:layout_height="36dip"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/abc_dropdownitem_text_padding_left"
                  android:paddingRight="@dimen/abc_dropdownitem_text_padding_right"
                  android:singleLine="true"
                  android:ellipsize="end"
                  android:background="@null"
                  android:inputType="text|textAutoComplete|textNoSuggestions"
                  android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                  android:dropDownHeight="wrap_content"
                  android:dropDownAnchor="@id/search_edit_frame"
                  android:dropDownVerticalOffset="0dip"
                  android:dropDownHorizontalOffset="0dip" />

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/search_close_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dip"
                    android:paddingRight="8dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/abc_searchview_description_clear" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/submit_area"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/search_go_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dip"
                    android:paddingRight="16dip"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/abc_searchview_description_submit" />

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/search_voice_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dip"
                    android:paddingRight="16dip"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/abc_searchview_description_voice" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is what I 'm getting. The left action menu view has an MenuItem defined via xml and has custom styling (applied through actionButtonStyle property in Toolbar's theme).

The right action menu view has a searchview MenuItem defined via xml

The same result is if I move SearchView to the left menu.

[image]

Can somebody explain to me how to strip the searchIcon image of its padding and/or right margin?

PS: This is the expanded SearchView. Notice the right part, where I click the button. It is obviously expanded to full width without margins
[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here's what I think is happening.

Notice this line

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
```

I think the actionButtonStyle of the Toolbar gets applied twice. I haven't had the time to look it into depth...

If anyone's got any comment, be my guest :)